# What if error of linear regression is uncorrelated between different observations, but dependent?

Tags: regression, least-squares, residuals, error

One of the assumptions of classic linear regression is that error is uncorrelated between different observations. But it is obvious that uncorrelated is not independent. I have already learn the situation of correlated errors. But I am thinking are there any situations that errors are uncorrelated $\operatorname{Cov}(\varepsilon_i,\varepsilon_j)=0$, but also dependent? What should we do for that situation? And how can we detect that?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated and a major +1 for this question. I don’t have a thorough answer, but to imagine how errors are uncorrelated but dependent, imagine a situation where knowing that an error is large in magnitude corresponds to the next error probably being large in magnitude. Since you don’t know the direction, this relationship is not correlation, but it is a relationship. I could imagine this in financial situations: after a big loss, people might be eager to “buy the dip” and increase the price back up a lot, but a big loss also could indicate future large losses.

Comment: I wonder whether anything needs to be done at all, because none of the conditions required for the validity of OLS results is violated.

Comment: Echoing Dave's comment, if this dependence occurs in a time series setting, then it suggests to me that you can get better predictions by using the conditional distribution of the potential future data, given all the past data, than by using OLS regression. In other words, even no major assumptions of OLS are violated, it still might not be optimal in terms of obtaining predictions when you have such dependence.

Answer (score 1):

With uncorrelated errors, the linear regression coefficient estimates and standard errors should still be correct; tests and confidence intervals will not be correct in general ― e.g. the significance level and coverage respectively may differ from what you want ― but in large samples this might not matter all that much.

"Dependence" ― even under the restriction of 0 correlation ― can cover a very wide variety of possibilities. Consequently, if you don't have a specific form of dependence in mind to check for, it can be hard to detect (very large samples may be required to get good power against very broad alternatives).

Answer (score 1):

The Gauss–Markov theorem has among its assumptions that

- the errors are uncorrelated (but not necessarily independent);
- the errors are homoscedastic and have expectation zero (but are not necessarily identically distributed).

The conclusion of the theorem is that among all estimators of the coefficients in the linear model that are linear combinations of the values of the response variables, the ones with the smallest mean squared error are the least-squares estimators.

Comment: Yes you are right, within linear unbias estimator. But I think my question is not fully answered.